# Reflection doesn't work for CCScene, why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a sub-class of CCLayer, named MyScene.  In the App Delegate I added this code:

```
-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];

    if( [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] != nil ) {
        if( [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] isKindOfClass:[MyScene class]] ) {
            MyScene *scene = (MyScene*) [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene];
            [scene goingToBackground];
    }
}
```

}

The app has a running scene, and I know it's MyScene, but isKindOfClass doesn't return YES.  Why?

Comment: I've added CCLOG statements so I know the applicationDidEnterBackground is being called and I know that runningScene is not nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene]`  always returns a CCScene not a CCLayer object.
As you are comparing a CCScene with your CCLayer sub class i.e. MyScene so it always return false. Try to set the tag of your MyScene object and get that object by tag and the compare it. it will return YES

Comment: That's a great way of doing it.  Thanks Inder.

Comment: Thanks. And use appropriate naming for your classes. If your subclass name would be MyLayer instead of MyScene that would have rally helped you...